# How do you use Models in a master page with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, master-pages

public ActionResult Index(){

```
         var dataContext = new DataEvidencijaDataContext();



         MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();   
         string KorisnickoIme = myObject.UserName.ToString();     

        var user = from i in dataContext.korisniks
                   where i.korisnik1 == KorisnickoIme
                   select i;
        ViewData.Add("user", user);
        return View(user);
    }
```

In master page i put this 
<%= Html.RenderPartial("profPredmeti", ViewData["user"])%>
but this is not work

Comment: @ognjenb, Trying to rephrase to understand: You want to create menus dynamically in an ASP.NET MVC project's Master Page? Correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Menu items is records from database.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Are you using strongly typed views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RenderAction](http://www.andreas-schlapsi.com/2008/11/01/renderaction-and-subcontrollers-in-aspnet-mvc/) for this to delegate menu rendering to some controller. Another option is to have your controller (or base controller class, or action filter) put the menu object into ViewData, and then your master page will do

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MenuRenderView", ViewData["menu"]) %>
```

where MenuRenderView.aspx partial view consumes the menu object from ViewData["menu"]. What does this object contain depends on your database/code.

Comment: at the beginning of the page I put code, queries confirmed to work well

Comment: To my knowledge .Add() will fail if there's already "user" key while View["user"] = user will overwrite the value; the choice is yours...

Comment: how call Html.RenderPartial from master page with this Index() action

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I have taken in the past is to have a base controller class from which all the other controllers inherit.  In that base controller class, you can add items into ViewData after the controller is initialized:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    ViewData.Add("CommonPageData", CommonPageData);
}
```

The "CommonPageData" in this case is a property or type *CommonPageData* (a custom class) whose properties are lazy-loaded.  One of the properties is a navigation item collection that is consumed on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

User **RenderPartial** for the Menu, but you're gonna need to pass in the ViewData the datasource for the menu all the time, a solution is to make **an abstract BaseController** and to put the datasource in the ViewData in the **constructor** of that base controller
all the controllers will inherit from the base controller

Comment: calling ViewData from  controller I dont understand

Comment: adding value to the viewdata in the contructor of the base controller, so you can use it in your masterpage

Answer (score 0):

I have this block sitting in my `Site.Master` page:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        MasterModel = SiteMasterViewData.Get();
    }

    protected SiteMasterViewData MasterModel;
</script>
```

That `Get()` method is a static factory method tacked on to the View Data class. All of this is embarrassing but here we are.